# What is wrong with this query? i am using vb script to insert data to access database

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert some data into a Microsoft Access database but all these queries are wrong it seems. Whenever I run my query I will get syntax error near INSERT INTO statements.

Following are my queries; can any one tell me the correct syntax?

First query :

```
strst = "USE Employee_Data INSERT INTO Employee_Data (loginID,fName,lName,Number) VALUES (""" & user & """,""" & firstname & """,""" & lastname & """, """ & phonenumber & """)"
```

Second query :

```
strst = "USE Employee_Data INSERT INTO Employee_Data (loginID,fName,lName,Number) VALUES (""user"", ""firstname"", ""lastname"", ""phonenumber"")"
```

Third query :

```
dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO Employees " _
    & "(userID, fName, lName, Number) VALUES " _
    & "(user, firstname, lastname, phonenumber);"
```

Fourth Query :

```
strst = "INSERT INTO Employee_Data (loginID,fName,lName,Number) VALUES ([" & user & "], [" &firstname& "], [" & lastname & "], [" &phonenumber & "]);"
```

Fifth query :

```
  strst = "USE Employee_Data INSERT INTO Employee_Data (loginID,fName,lName,Number) VALUES ([user],[firstname],[lastname],[phonenumber])"
```

Comment: What error? What is actually wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Access should still be okay with single quotes:

```
strst = "USE Employee_Data INSERT INTO Employee_Data (loginID,fName,lName,Number) VALUES ('" & user & "','" & firstname & "','" & lastname & "', '" & phonenumber & "')"
```